# Существуют ли слова «папонька» и «мамонька»?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, существительные, суффиксы

Ребенок в третьем классе использовал суффикс и образовал такие слова от *папа* и *мама*; поставили четверку, слова зачеркнули.

Answer (score 3):

Если просто отвечать на вопрос (есть или нет?), то такие слова, конечно же, есть.
А вот как часто встречаются, где и когда — это уже другое дело.

• С мамой проще: однокоренное слово имеется в орфографическом словаре: [мамонька](https://lopatin.academic.ru/63127/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0).

•• О папоньке

Из статьи "Номинация отца в архангельских говорах" (И. Б. Качинская; [*стр.300*](http://msk.phil.spbu.ru/nauchnye-temy/srg16xeFINAL.pdf)):

> На словообразовательном уровне значение ʼродной отецʼ затрагивает 4 основных корня (и их вариации): <...> **пап-** (*папа, папо, папанец, папанька, папаня, папаша, папашка, папенька, папка, **папонька**, папочка, папушка, папынька*).

Из рассказа детского писателя Л. И. Кузьмина ["Малые Звоны"](https://sharlib.com/read_151644-3):
*— Ой, **папонька**, позвони! Ой, миленький, возьми молоточек, стукни скорей по наковаленке!*

Из *Мотивационного словаря сибирского говора* (под ред. О. И. Блиновой; [*стр. 21*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/287486122.pdf)):

> П**А**ПОНЬКА, м. Ласк. к папа.
> СМ: мамонька ‘ласк. к мама’.
> *— Уж ты, **папонька**, родненький казак, ты скажи, где наша мамонька* (из песни).

Нечасто эти слова встречаются, нечасто. Возможно, педагог посчитал их украинизмами, или не знал об исключениях из правил, или подумал, что в третьем классе эти исключения не обязательно знать ([Правописание суффиксов существительных](https://yarus.asu.edu.ru/?id=92)):
Исключения: *мамонька и маменька, папонька и папенька*;
Запомни! *паинька, заинька, баиньки*.

Answer (score 1):

Таких нету, есть очень похожие: *пап**е**нька* и *мам**е**нька.* В художественной литературе часто можно встретить.

Comment: [Мамонька](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мамонька) есть (в других источниках тоже), а вот папе не повезло :)) , хотя встречается и [папонька](https://morphologyonline.ru/папонька).

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее *разговорные слова*. Хотя в литературных произведениях тоже встречаются (см. ответ `@Римма Михайлова`), но в основном только в диалогах, то есть **чтобы создать этими словами "атмосферу разговора" и передать непринуждённую речь героев**.

А в контрольных работах лучше использовать слова, которые **точно** существуют, чтобы не возникало таких неприятностей `=)`.